# How to use react testing library to type text into formik when value is controlled?

Tags: reactjs, formik, react-testing-library

I'm currently having problems writing tests for formik fields that use value. I've managed to get my tests to work if instead of value I use defaultValue but I need to use value. I have tried to console.log in the onChange and know that text is flowing through it but I don't understand why it isn't setting. What do I need to change so that it works?

Example of code I'm trying to test

```js
    <TextField
       id="name"
       label="Profile Name"
       onChange={formik.handleChange}
       value={formik.values.name}
       required
   </TextField>
```

Example of code that the test works on

```js
    <TextField
       id="name"
       label="Profile Name"
       onChange={formik.handleChange}
       defaultValue={formik.values.name}
       required
   </TextField>
```

The currently failing test

```js
    test("fills out profile name", () => {
            const field = screen.getByLabelText("Profile Name");
            userEvent.type(field, "profile name");
            expect(field).toHaveValue("profile name");
          });
```

The screen.debug that is telling me the text isn't being set.

```js
     <input
            aria-invalid="false"
            aria-labelledby="TextFieldLabel24"
            class="ms-TextField-field field-80"
            id="name"
            required=""
            type="text"
            value=""
          />
```

Comment: const field = screen.getByLabelText("Profile Name");
Does the field have the correct value?

Comment: It starts with the correct value of an empty string. It has never shown me the correct expected value in the input.

Comment: try wrapping your onChange like await waitFor(async () => { await userEvent.type(field, "profile name"); })

Answer (score 2):

Have you ever tried asynchronous? If the field has got the correct value, asynchronous can be the problem.

```
 test("fills out profile name", async () => {
     const field = screen.getByLabelText("Profile Name");
     await userEvent.type(field, "profile name");
     expect(field).toHaveValue("profile name");
 });
```

Comment: I have tried using async but it hasn't worked. I double checked just now with your suggestion and the value is still an empty string.

Answer (score 0):

Try adding a delay to your call to `userEvent.type()`. For example:

`await userEvent.type(field, "profile name", { delay: 1 })`

Comment: If I try a delay, does this mean I need an await for afterwards? I tried the delay then tried to debug by adding this after it`await waitFor(() => {
    screen.debug(screen.getByLabelText("Profile Name"));
  });`It still showed me that same empty input. Is this wrong?

Answer (score 0):

I was facing the same issue and I am able to resolve it by just removing the `value` attribute from the input box. Not sure why it cause an issue when we provide it but below is the code.

**Working**

```
it('Test input field with different values', async () => {
    render(<input placeholder="test_placeholder" />)

    const input = screen.getByPlaceholderText('test_placeholder');

    userEvent.clear(input);
    userEvent.type(input, 'Test');
    
    await waitFor(() => { expect(input.value).toEqual('Test') });

    userEvent.clear(input);
    userEvent.type(input, '@#$%');
    
    await waitFor(() => { expect(input.value).toEqual('@#$%') });
})
```

Even if I do render with blank value then the same code is not working. Some how `userEvent.type` does not have any effect when value attribute is present.

**Not Working**

```
render(<input placeholder="test_placeholder"  value=""/>)
```

It keeps value as empty string *(or whatever we gave during render)* through out the test.

[image: Failed Test Case]

> **Notes :-**
>
> 1] I have used Formik only in my actual application and the behavior
> is same for it as well. To short down the code I have just rendered
> raw input here.
>
> 2]. Below are the version of my testing library
>
> [image]
>
> 3]. I have used `userEvent.clear` here, otherwise values are getting appended and the 2nd test would become `.toEqual('Test@#$%')`
>
> 4]. Add `onChange={()=>{}}` with input to avoid warnings.